# Sum values from month

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a table of values, dates and categories:

```
5   1.09.2013   red
-7  2.09.2013   red
9   21.09.2013  red
-2  3.10.2013   red
11  28.09.2013  green
3   2.10.2013   green
8   16.10.2013  green
```

I calculate sum of values where category is green with:

```
=sum(filter(A:A;C:C="green"))
```

How to sum just values from October where category is green ?

Answer (score 1):

The following formula can help:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A:A, C:C = "green", VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(B:B, "^\d+\.|\.\d+$", "")) >= 10))
```

**UPDATE**

Here a sample with the test data set.

[image]

Comment: It does not work for me, also I need to use semicolons instead of comma, but still no luck

Comment: @rumburak I updated the post with the sample data. Perhaps the problem has to do with the entire dataset.